# Connect to PCs on different network

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, home-networking, cable-modem, windows-networking

Setup:
Modem has build it router that set to 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0
to that modem is connected another router with IP 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 (I can't access router's config, so not sure how it's setup)

All PCs that connected to the modem have IPs 192.168.0.x

All PCs that connected to the router have IPs 192.168.1.x

Is there a way connect (Windows file sharing) from PC on modem's network to PCs on router's network?

[EDIT]
It seems router computers can access modem computers via IP, but not by computer name, but modem computers can't access router computers even via IP.

Comment: Give the nested router it's own static IP address and then turn off its DHCP server. Then all of your devices will get IPs from the upstream router/modem and all the devices will be on the same network.

Comment: As I mentioned, I can't change router's config...

Comment: Why can't you change it? Can you connect all PCs to the same device?

Comment: I don't have login information for the router (and yes, I know how to reset it, I'm trying avoid it). I can change settings in the modem though. Also, I just found out, that I can ping IPs of modem computers from router computers, but not the other way around, also Windows doesn't see computers on different networks when browsing workgroup

Comment: No, it's not possible if you can't change the config of the router. Otherwise refer to method 1 if the answer below. (Method 2 is if you only want to accesss one PC/server)

Comment: Yes, computers connected to the router can access computers connected to the modem (just like the internet). But you'll never ever achieve the other way around because of WAN security without the ability to change the routers config.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done - there are at least 2 major ways (with further variance)

Method 1 - Convert router to AP/Switch
You ideally would reconfigure the router as a switch / AP - including disabling DHCP and connecting the modem to the LAN port. This would work, but would put more load in the modem, and would require a change of IP address on the router network.

Method 2 - Allow router to accept SAMBA connections on its WAN interface

To do this -

1. Set up a DMZ on the router to point to the Windows server [ or map
   all the appropriate ports across ] and
2. Change WAN IP address on the router to a fixed IP address in the 192.168.0.x range, but outside the DHCP range.
3. Refer to the SAMBA server as \192.168.0.x\yyyyyyy where X is the static IP address you assigned it.

Comment: OP mentioned wanting to access multiple PCs on routers network. So method 2 is not an option. But because it was mentioned it is a home-network (see tags and term workgroup) method 1 is perfectly fine and the load wouldn't be a problem with normal home-use.